# Using visual themes in a game

Tags: java, animation

In my small application, I need to use a variety of visual themes.

The simplified structure of this class:

> ```
> Theme
>   |
>   .__ menu
>   |     |
>   |     .__ screenBackground
>   |     .__ itemsColor
>   |     .__ getRandomItemAnimation()
>   |
>   .__ game
>   |     |
>   |     .__ screenBackground
>   |     .__ gameBoardBackground
>   |     .__ getRandomMoveSound()
>   |
>   .__ getRandomStartScreenImage()
> ```

I want to write code like this:

```
setBackground(theme.game.screenBackground)
```

instead of

```
setBackground(theme.game().screenBackground())
```

But in addition to that, I want to use inheritance. However, Java does not seem to allow to override public fields of the parent class in the descendant classes.

So I've decided to use the following implementation:

**Basic classes:**

```java
// All constructors (in the next 3 classes) used to set final class-members by descendants

public abstract class Theme {
    public final MenuTheme menu;
    public final GameTheme game;

    public abstract Image getRandomStartScreenImage();

    public Theme(MenuTheme menuTheme, GameTheme gameTheme) {
        this.menuTheme = menuTheme;
        this.gameTheme = gameTheme;
    }
}

public abstract class MenuTheme {
    public final Image screenBackground;
    public final Color itemsColor;

    public abstract Animation getRandomItemAnimation();

    public MenuTheme(Image screenBackground, Color itemsColor) {
        this.screenBackground = screenBackground;
        this.itemsColor = itemsColor;
    }
}

public abstract class GameTheme {
    public final Image screenBackground;
    public final Image gameBoardBackground;

    public abstract Sound getRandomMoveSound();

    public GameTheme(Image screenBackground, Image gameBoardBackground) {
        this.screenBackground = screenBackground;
        this.gameBoardBackground = gameBoardBackground;
    }
}
```

**Using:**

```java
public class Menu {
    public void setUp() {
        Theme theme = GameContext.getCurrentTheme();
        setBackground(theme.menu.screenBackground);
        setItemsColor(theme.menu.itemsColor);
    }

    public void onClickItem(Item clickedItem) {
        Theme theme = GameContext.getCurrentTheme();
        clickedItem.startAnimation(theme.menu.getRandomItemAnimation());
        // Action action = getActionByItem(clickedItem);
        // action.start();
    }
}
```

**How to add theme:**

```java
public class DarkTheme extends Theme {
    private Image[] startScreenImages = getStartScreenImages();

    public Image getRandomStartScreenImage() {
        return startScreenImages[getRandomIndex()];
    }

    public DarkTheme() {
        super(new DarkMenuTheme(), new DarkGameTheme());
    }
}

public class DarkMenuTheme extends MenuTheme {
    private Animation[] itemAnimations = getItemAnimations();

    public Animation getRandomItemAnimation() {
        return itemAnimations[getRandomIndex()];
    }

    public DarkMenuTheme() {
        super(getDarkMenuScreenBackground(), getDarkMenuItemsColor());
    }
}

public class DarkGameTheme {
    private Sound[] moveSounds = getMoveSounds();

    public Sound getRandomMoveSound() {
        return moveSounds[randomIndex()];
    }

    public DarkGameTheme() {
        super(getDarkGameScreenBackground(), getDarkGameBoardBackground());
    }
}
```

What do you think about the structure of `Theme`?  Does it look like a good implementation?

The structure of `Theme` does not expect to be changed. There will only be the addition of new themes. Given this, what are the drawbacks and benefits of this code?  What improvement or other implementation can you recommend?

Comment: You might find the cons in the first answer relevant: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/190955/using-public-final-rather-than-private-getters

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I want to write code like this:
>   setBackground(theme.game.screenBackground) instead of
>   setBackground(theme.game().screenBackground())

Read this : http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?AccessorsAreEvil

The URL is misleading, it is a 'balanced' article, the part I want you to pay particularly attention is this:

> The examples [...] they are really structures (data), not quite
>   objects.

Your theme class should really be a structure, and be too simple to have getters.

In response to @bowmore, the Theme should not be responsible for loading resources, the theme should really return resource identifiers.

If it were me, by the way, I would probably go for

`game.drawBackground()`

where game knows what the theme is, and gets from theme the resource name for the background which a loader class then loads and a UI class then displays.

Answer (score 4):

> I want to write code like this: `setBackground(theme.game.screenBackground)` instead of `setBackground(theme.game().screenBackground())`.

Why would you sacrifice encapsulation ([the first principle of object-oriented design](http://www.netobjectives.com/files/Encapsulation_First_Principle_Object_Oriented_Design.pdf)) for the minor convenience of not having to type brackets?

I frankly cannot see any real benefits, while I can see several drawbacks :

- themes will have to be fully initialized upon construction
- lazy loading or initialising is difficult if not impossible, the nested exposure of fields makes even proxy implementations a difficult option. This is especially painful for fields that refer to heavyweight objects that likely must be read from a file (Images, Sound)
- the API does not communicate that these fields are not mutable.

I believe these points would also be valid in other languages than Java.

Answer (score 1):

A one liner suggestion

- Make the constructors of abstract class `protected` ([public is pointless](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/761854/oo-why-should-constructors-on-abstract-classes-be-protected-not-public)).

Answer (score 1):

Based on the answers you gave, I came to this decision:

**Base classes:**

```
// fictional class only to present Id-type here
public class Id {
    public static enum image {
        COSMOS,
        SPACEMAN,
        SPACESHIP,
        FROG_ASTRONAUT
    }
    public static enum sound {
        SHOT,
        DETONATION,
        GRUNT
    }
    public static enum color {
        RED,
        GREEN,
        BLUE,
        BLACK,
        WHITE
    }
    public static enum animation {
        DAMPING,
        BLINKING,
        SHAKE
    }
}

public abstract class Theme {
    public final MenuTheme menu;
    public final GameTheme game;
    public abstract Id.image startScreenImageId();

    protected Theme(MenuTheme menuTheme, GameTheme gameTheme) {
        this.menu = menuTheme;
        this.game = gameTheme;
    }
}

public interface MenuTheme {
    Id.image screenBackgroundId();
    Id.color itemColor();
    Id.animation itemAnimationId();
}

public interface GameTheme {
    Id.image screenBackgroundId();
    Id.image gameBoardBackgroundId();
    Id.sound moveSoundId();
}
```

**Example of Theme:**

```
public class CosmosTheme extends Theme {
    public CosmosTheme() {
        super(new CosmosMenuTheme(), new CosmosGameTheme());
    }

    @Override
    public Id.image startScreenImageId() {
        return Id.image.SPACEMAN;
    }
}

class CosmosMenuTheme implements MenuTheme {
    @Override
    public Id.image screenBackgroundId() {
        return Id.image.FROG_ASTRONAUT;
    }

    @Override
    public Id.color itemColor() {
        return Id.color.BLUE;
    }

    @Override
    public Id.animation itemAnimationId() {
        return Id.animation.SHAKE;
    }
}

class CosmosGameTheme implements GameTheme {
    private static final Id.sound[] MOVE_SOUNDS_IDS = {
            Id.sound.DETONATION, Id.sound.SHOT, Id.sound.GRUNT
    };

    @Override
    public Id.image screenBackgroundId() {
        return Id.image.COSMOS;
    }

    @Override
    public Id.image gameBoardBackgroundId() {
        return Id.image.SPACESHIP;
    }

    @Override
    public Id.sound moveSoundId() {
        Random random = new Random();
        random.setSeed(System.nanoTime());
        int randomIndex = random.nextInt(MOVE_SOUNDS_IDS.length);
        return MOVE_SOUNDS_IDS[randomIndex];
    }
}
```

**And:**

```
public class ThemeInfoProvider {
    public String getInfoAbout(Theme theme) {
        StringBuilder info = new StringBuilder();
        String themeName = theme.getClass().getSimpleName();
        appendAllToBuilder(info,
            themeName, "\n",
            "    startScreenImage:  ", theme.startScreenImageId().name(), "\n",
            "    menu:\n",
            "        screenBackground:  ", theme.menu.screenBackgroundId().name(), "\n",
            "        itemColor:         ", theme.menu.itemColor().name(), "\n",
            "        itemAnimation:     ", theme.menu.itemAnimationId().name(), "\n",
            "    game:\n",
            "        screenBackground:     ", theme.game.screenBackgroundId().name(), "\n",
            "        gameBoardBackground:  ", theme.game.gameBoardBackgroundId().name(), "\n",
            "        moveSound:            ", theme.game.moveSoundId().name(), "\n",
            "\n"
        );
        return info.toString();
    }

    public void appendAllToBuilder(StringBuilder builder, String... toAppend) {
        for (String each : toAppend) {
            builder.append(each);
        }
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ThemeInfoProvider themeInfoProvider = new ThemeInfoProvider();
        System.out.println(themeInfoProvider.getInfoAbout(new CosmosTheme()));
    }
}
```

That is, I use resource identifiers instead of resources, final-fields I use only for nested themes - access to any of the resource identifiers costs only a single pair of parentheses.

In getters I do not use the prefix get - IMO, so looks better. It seems to me that for a typical data structure (because Theme does not have the behavior), this prefix is superfluous. Or is it not so?